# Creating a press page for our project

Tags: plugins, php, excerpt, code

Over time our project got some good press: press releases, interviews, media appearances

Now I want to create a "press page" (something like [this](https://talktothemanager.com/press)). Requirements:

- is easy to update - everyone can write html at some degree, the procedure for adding a new article on the press page should be straightforward
- aggregates content from the original articles - a picture, title, maybe an abstract(excerpts )
- bind in my current theme (cannot be changed atm)

How can I achieve this? Is there any plugin I can use?

Comment: **I suggest you to take a look at the following website links** http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types
http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/08/complete-guide-custom-post-types/ These are really handy. In your question you did not write if its for an already exisiting theme/template or for a regular user (no developer). That would give the people and me on wordpress answers a better insight of how to guide you through your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the custom post types for Press Releases, News etc with external website links with [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/press-news-events/).

You have to just list those custom post types where you want to display those.

Answer (score 0):

The "PressRoom by Newswire" (a free plugin that I authored) creates a press room page on the user's website. It will also helps the user publish and distribute press releases.  PressRoom by Newswire allows the user to create "pin style" content blocks for the new press room page.  Control over the style of these blocks is provided through an interface that allows the user to choose backgrounds, colors, borders, headers, footers, etc. The plugin settings provide a CSS window to change other aspects of the press room page.

PressRoom by Newswire includes 8 custom post type interfaces.  These new interfaces can be used to create different kinds of content blocks for the press room page:

•   Press Release Blocks
•   Embed Blocks
•   Image Albums
•   Quote Blocks
•   Social Media Blocks
•   Link Blocks
•   Contact Blocks
•   Text Blocks

Each of the press room blocks created by the user becomes a widget that is available for use elsewhere on the website.

The plugin is currently under review with WordPress right now (should be available from them at https://wordpress.org/plugins/pressroom-by-newswire/ shortly) in the mean time, it is available for free on my website:

Comment: Please see [how to merge your two accounts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).